# What does shutdown mean for the IR2184

Tags: driver, bridge

I'm trying to understand & design a circuit using two IR2184 half bridge drivers and some n channel mosfets to create a full H-bridge to control a motor.

Reading the datasheet for the IR2184 it mentions that there is a shutdown state. One of the pins on the IC is also marked shutdown and from the logic diagram appears to have an internal pullup resistor.

I assume therefore that in order to bring the IC from it's shutdown state to an active state I have to pull that pin to ground.

What I'm not sure about though is what does shutdown mean for the IC? Is it simply that regardless of the input both high and low outputs will remain low and therefore both mosfet gates will be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think figure three in the datasheet shows you what happens to the outputs when shutdown goes low.  There's also a diagram of how the internals work.  So it looks like once shutdown goes low there is a delay and then your outputs will go low.

[image]